# How to create a user screen lock page when the user is already logged in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I Can get my user name with this Controller action result:

```
public ActionResult LockScreen(string UserName)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And my action link is from Header Page:

```
 <li><a href="@Url.Action("LockScreen", "Account", new { UserName = 
 User.Identity.Name }  )" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
 <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i> Lock</a></li>
```

**So I want a Screenlock Page like this for example current user Name is Jhon Doe:**
https://imgur.com/KRfg7DI

And the current user will use a **password** and return view to last **redirect page to unlocked screen** if the user go back to previous page or change this link **user will not access any page until use a password in LockScreen Page**

Answer (score 0):

[Actually I post this question also in asp.net forum and I got quickly answer for this post so click me to view the answer....](https://forums.asp.net/t/2130729.aspx?How%20to%20create%20a%20lockscreen%20for%20identity%20User%20and%20Unlock%20Screen%20with%20Identity%20User%20Password)